# Find contours of touching objects as two distinct contours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm wondering how to count objects that are connected to each other as two distinct objects using cv2.findContours in Python

For example this image :

[image]

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Will output one contour.
What can I do to get two contours instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by converting your input image to edge image and then detecting contours. But in this case, there is a break in edge image(I tried with canny) at the intersection of the two objects as shown below.

Break in Canny:

[image: break in canny]

Whereas the expected edge image should have all the pixels at the boundary as white.

Expected edge image:

[image: expected edge image]

Thus to get this perfect edge image, I have created an algo shared below(This algo will work only on a binary image like this with objects filled with white color).

Before using this algo, make sure that the object does not lie on the boundary, that is, all the boundary pixels of the image should be black. If not black, add a border on all sides of the image of black colour and length 1 pixel.

```
# Creating black image of same shape and single channel
edge = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype = np.uint8)
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Iterating over each pixel except those at the boundary
for i in range(1, h-1):
    for j in range(1, w-1):
        # if current pixel is white
        if img[i][j] == 255:
            # roi is the image of 9 pixel from around the current pixel
            roi = img[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2].copy()
            # Counting number of black pixel in the neighbourhood of current pixel
            blackCount = np.sum(roi == 0)
            # if a neighbouring pixel is black, then current pixel is a boundary pixel.
            if blackCount > 0:
                edge[i][j] = 255
```

After finding the edge image, get all the contours in the image:

```
cont, hier = cv2.findContours(edge, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

For this image, you will get 3 contours, 2 for the two objects and 1 for the two objects combined. To eliminate the contour of both the objects combined, use the hierarchy information.

```
# I am taking only those contours which do not have a child contour.
finalContours = np.asarray([cont[i] for i in range(len(cont)) if hier[0][i][2] == -1])
```

"finalContours" will have the 2 contours for the two objects.

[Refer to this link for more information about the parent-child relationship of the contours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html#)